# References for Programming In Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7

What References Can I Use for Programming in Windows 7 in C#?

Comment: What do you mean by optimize? What platform do you use (WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET)?

Comment: .NET is designed to do such optimizing for you, so you can focus on building the actual application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of resources around.

You may want to check:

- [Windows 7 Training Kit For Developers](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=1C333F06-FADB-4D93-9C80-402621C600E7&displaylang=en)
- [Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 Application Quality Cookbook](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows7AppQuality)
- [Five Steps to Windows 7 Application Readiness](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620524.aspx)
- [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e49820cb-954d-45ae-9cb3-1b9e8ea7fe8c)
- [Windows 7 Programming Guide - Taskbar](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2010/05/03/windows-7-programming-guide-taskbar.aspx)
- [Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)
- [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en)

Book: [Introducing Windows 7 for Developers](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Book.aspx?ID=13697&locale=en-us)

> There are no language specific (C#) features to programming for Windows 7 but you can enhance user's experience by utilising some of new features available in Windows 7. Many of them available in WPF 4 but can be used alone e.g. via [Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [Images.Show](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/XP2Win7), which is a sample application that shows how to migrate an XP application to use Windows 7 features.